# Is there a reason to only do gigs from a certain fixer?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I've gotten multiple gigs from multiple fixers around Night City, is there a reason to favor one over the other or are they all just generic "quest givers" depending on the certain part of the city that I'm in?

Is there a reputation system or does a certain fixer favor a certain gang?

Comment: I haven't quite gotten far enough in the game to be certain, but I believe that the various Fixers you meet all handle gigs in different areas. So favoring one would just mean you do more work / spend more time in their area of Night City.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to only do gigs for only one fixer. There is sort of a reputation with the fixer, but it isn't negatively affected by doing gigs for other fixers. This may not hold true for the main storyline. I would recommend completing as many gigs as possible unless you are speedrunning.